# How to disable region collapsing or expand ALL regions in Visual Studio VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio C# (2008), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> expand all the regions.

There's also a setting in menu:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced
```

to not collapse during file open. I see no equivalents in VB.NET.

Is there a way to expand all the regions, not just the one which has focus in VB.NET?

Or a macro or add-in that does it? I just hate not being able to see all the code.

Comment: I reset the settings and it's still not working. It works in C# but not vb.net. The only thing working in vb.net is collapsing/expanding the region the cusrosr is on via ctril-M-M. I have read posts on the web about others having the same issue like this one although it pertains to VS 2005. [http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETVisualBasic/Oct2005/post24342618.asp](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETVisualBasic/Oct2005/post24342618.asp) This solution worked for me which involves using a Macro. (If someone created a macro, then the problem is real. I am sure region functionality

Comment: This: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shanewho.IHateRegions#overview

Comment: This: https://github.com/fsdsabel/ExpandRegions/releases (others extensions are abandoned/did not seem to work in 2019)

Answer (score 28):

In Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 there is an option for deactivating collapsing (called 'outlining mode').

You can find it under:

```
Text-Editor->Basic->VB Specific
```

and then uncheck "Enable outlining mode".

But you will then lose the feature for collapse/expand at all.

Comment: For C# developers this can be found under `Text Editor` -> `C#` -> `Advanced` -> `Enter outlining mode when files open`. Uncheck this option and regions will be disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't seem to use 'outlining mode' _without_ having it all collapsed by default.

Answer (score 10):

If you are willing to remove regions you can try this:

<kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>

- Quick Replace
- Find Options
- Use: Regular Expressions

**Find What:**

```
^\s*#(end)?region.*$
```

**Replace with:**

```
[leave replace box empty]
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Match the start of a line
- `\s*` - Match zero or more whitespace characters
- `#` - Match one `#` character
- `(end)?` - Optionally match the string `end`
- `region` - Match the string `region`
- `.*` - Match zero or more of any other characters
- `$` - Match the end of the line

This will effectively find all `#region` or `#endregion` lines, whether they are indented or not, and whether they have description text after them or not.

Answer (score 7):

In the Edit Menu, the Outlining submenu, you have all the options. Including *Toggle All Outlining* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> by default).

Maybe your key mappings were altered.

If you so desire, you can even select menu:

```
Edit -> Outlining -> Stop Outlining
```

Comment: The corresponding commands to change the shortcuts are `Edit.ToggleAllOutlining` and `Edit.StopOutlining`

Answer (score 3):

In VB.Net, do a Search and Replace and select Use Hidden and Use Regex:

Replace:

```
^.*\#(end)*(:Wh)*region.*\n
```

With:

Comment: works with c# aswell, http://www.brianschmitt.com/2010/01/clear-visual-studio-regions.html

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extension to do this (and more), and it works for VB and C#.  See this answer for more info:

[Hiding the regions in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858132/hiding-the-regions-in-visual-studio/6179771#6179771)

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty odd. The default profile settings for VB.Net and C# should bind the outlining functions to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combos.

It's possible that your profile is in a weird state. Try resetting your profile to VB.Net settings and see if that fixes the problem.

`Tools` → `Import / Export Settings` → `Reset All Settings` → `VB.Net Profile`

Answer (score 1):

Once I changed:

```
#Region Form Level Events
#End Region
```

To (note the addition of quotes):

```
#Region "Form Level Events"
#End Region
```

The minus signed appeared and I was able to collapse/expand Regions.

Answer (score -3):

I came up with this trick:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

- Quick Replace
- Find:

> #Region

- Search in: current document (or entire project or wherever you need to expand regions)
- Search in hidden text

Then press <kbd>Return</kbd> and keep it pressed until VS notify the search is endend.
As a result all your '#region's have been expanded in very few seconds.