# Visual studio setting or plugin to "hide" region directives in the IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, regions

In our team we have people that love and hate the "#region" directive. I am looking for a way to make both sides happy. We use VS2010.

I know that you can go to tools > options > text editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Enter outlining mode when files open", as explained in this question:

[How to permanently disable region-folding in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115694/how-to-permanently-disable-region-folding-in-visual-studio-2008)

However, this is not what I am loking for as it disables all collapsing and the #region text still appears on the screen.

The ideal solution would just hide on the fly the region directives (as if they weren't in the file). It should be just an IDE trick.

If nothing exists a pointer to a similar VS extension sample that could be used as a baseline would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3291/notdan) wrote an Visual Studio extension that disable the region.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179771