# Is there a way to have Visual Studio ignore regions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, editor

I'm working on a codebase that has so many regions that it is difficult to navigate the code and the collapse to definitions feature of visual studio is no longer useful.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to ignore the regions (or at least ignore them for the purposes of Collapse to Definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [I Hate #Regions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca) Extension expands all regions in your code and changes the `#region` font to be very hard to see. There is no way to hide them completely in standard VS.

Note you must be using the new (free) Community Edition or a paid edition of Visual Studio to use extensions.

You may also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858132/1218281) similar SO question.

Comment: Also fwiw the CodeMaid extension can remove them all